# issues Retrieving users profile picture from microsoft outlook account via Microsoft Graph 365 API in PHP

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Am trying to get microsoft outlook mail users profile photos using microsoft 365 graph API.

I have set the following permissions User.Read, **User.ReadWrite, User.ReadBasic.All, User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All** on the apps ends but its not displaying any profile photos whereas the user has Profile Photos already uploaded on her outlook mail account....

Below is the code

```
<?php 
session_start();

echo $acc= $_SESSION['access_token'];





$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array( 


CURLOPT_URL => "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo", 
//CURLOPT_URL => "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", 

CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", 
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30, 
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, 
//CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET", 
//CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "$data", 
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( 
"authorization: Bearer $acc"
), 
));

$response = curl_exec($curl); 
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);



print_r($response);
$json = json_decode($response);

$res = $json->{'items'};




if ($err) { 
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err; 
} else { 
//echo $response; 
}

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It isn't clear why type of account this is (personal vs work/school) or what error(s) you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there.  What you want to use is

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value
```

Comment: at Jason Rivera, when I add https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value  as you suggested
 , it  displays the following error  "error": { "code": "GetUserPhoto", "message": "The operation is not supported.", "innerError": { "request-id": "d10f8f9a-f361-4787-b7dd-766ac5b514f9", "date": "2017-12-01T02:09:40" } } }

Comment: At Marc LaFleur, the outlook  Microsoft email Account is a personal one

Comment: Ah, that might be the problem.  It works for school and work accounts.  I don't think it works for other Microsoft accounts.

Comment: At at Jason Rivera, how do I create either a Users work or school work  account  since my app leverages MSA 365 microsoft Graph API

Comment: You might have to try creating a new user in the Office 365 Admin Center.

Comment: One workaround for this is to use the beta API, which provides support for MSA profile photos. In other words, change the graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value endpoint to graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/photo/$value instead.

Comment: @DougMahugh That worked for me, thanks! I wonder when will this feature be ported over the the official release of the APIs, but so far the workaround works fine 

Comment: @DougMahugh Thanks for the beta API workaround. We've been upgrading apps that use the OneNote API which gave us access to the profile image and it was going to be a bit of a downer to have to tell users (with MSA accounts) that thanks to the upgrade to Microsoft Graph they were going to lose their profile images. So your pointer to the beta endpoint has been a godsend! [Read more about the beta GET photo operation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/profilephoto_get)  - as of July 1 2018, still not in the official release API.

Comment: As far as I can tell, getting a consumer profile photo using beta is now gone... :(