# How to retrieve username, email and image with OneDrive/Graph APIs?

Tags: c#, uwp, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, windows-community-toolkit

I'm working on a UWP app and I was thinking about moving from the old [LiveSDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn631819.aspx) (which is discontinued and was last updated around 2015) to the new OneDriveSDK (the Graph APIs), specifically using the UWP Community Toolkit Services package and its [APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/services/onedrive).

The library seems pretty easy to use as far as login and files/folders management go, but so far I haven't been able to find a way to retrieve the user full name, the user email and the profile picture.

Here's the code I'm currently using to do so, using LiveSDK (code simplified here):

```
public static async Task<(String username, String email)> GetUserProfileNameAndEmailAsync(LiveConnectSession session)
{
    LiveConnectClient connect = new LiveConnectClient(session);
    LiveOperationResult operationResult = await connect.GetAsync("me");
    IDictionary<String, object> results = operationResult.Result;
    String username = results["name"] as String;
    if (!(results["emails"] is IDictionary<string, object> emails)) return default;
    String email = emails["preferred"] as String ?? emails["account"] as String;
    return (username, email);
}

public static async Task<ImageSource> GetUserProfileImageAsync([NotNull] LiveConnectSession session)
{
    LiveConnectClient liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(session);
    LiveOperationResult operationResult = await liveClient.GetAsync("me/picture");
    String url = operationResult.Result?["location"] as String;

    // The URL points to the raw image data for the user profile picture, just download it
    return default;
}
```

I've looked at the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/migrating-from-live-sdk) and I see there seems to be a replacement for all of the above, but I haven't been able to integrate that with the UWP Toolkit service. For example, to retrieve the user info, here's what I've tried:

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/");
await OneDriveService.Instance.Provider.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(request);
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await OneDriveService.Instance.Provider.HttpProvider.SendAsync(request))    
{
    String content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();    
}
```

But this fails with an exception at the `SendAsync` call.

**NOTE:** I know there are the [Graph APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/services/microsoftgraph) too in the UWP Toolkit, with ready-to-use methods to retrieve the user info and profile picture, but apparently you need an office 365 subscription to use those APIs (both as a dev, and probably as a user too), so I guess that's not what I'm looking for here, since I've always been able to retrieve these info using a normal OneDrive client.

Is there a way to do this on UWP, either through some method within the UWP Toolkit, or with some other solution?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I've reused the code from the sample app, registered my app to get a clientID and made a quick test, but it's not working as expected and I'm getting this exception:

[image]

*Fixed, see below*

**EDIT #2:** According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47580669/issues-retrieving-users-profile-picture-from-microsoft-outlook-account-via-micro) question, I had to switch to `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta` to get the profile picture, as the `1.0` version of the APIs doesn't support it for normal MS accounts right now. All things considered, it seems to be working just fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/app-registration) document to register my app for Microsoft Graph. After that, I will get an application ID(in API, it's called as clientId).

Then, I used the [Microsoft Graph Connect Sample for UWP](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/uwp-csharp-connect-sample) to login in with my general MS account. It worked well. I could get the `username`, `email` etc.

Please note that if you want to run this sample successfully, you would need to use the application ID to initialize the `PublicClientApplication` object in `AuthenticationHelper.cs`.

```
public static PublicClientApplication IdentityClientApp = new PublicClientApplication("your client id");
```